# Instagram data scraping/crawling

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, instagram, conditional-statements

Is it legal to crawl or scrape Instagram?
I need to get some data but I don't really know if I should only use the official APIs.
Can you please reference the Terms and Conditions page in which I can find the answer?

Comment: ["Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Legal or illegal can only be defined within a certain area and a certain time and regard to a certain government.

Crawling and Scraping go **AGAINST** Instagram's [terms of use](https://help.instagram.com/478745558852511/), stating:

> You can't attempt to create accounts or access or collect information in unauthorized ways.
>   This includes creating accounts or collecting information in an automated way without our express permission.

Knowing that, make a decision for yourself :)